# Electric field lines in a uniformly charged dielectric solid sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, dielectric

What would electric field lines in the interior of a uniformly charged dielectric solid sphere (charge spread throughout the volume with a uniform charge density) look like? How do we even go about visualising field lines?

Comment: This is a standard exercise and it is covered in depth in most (all?) introductory textbooks.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I couldn't find it, would you point me to some book that does?

Comment: An exercise in Chapter 4 of  Griffiths's *Introduction to Electrodynamics* involves calculating the electric field of a uniformly charged dielectric sphere.  I don't have the fourth edition in front of me, but it's Exercise 4.20 in the third edition.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a sphere with uniformly distributed charge, the solution must be spherically symmetrical. Specifically, we know that the field intensity at a radius $r$ is proportional to the charge inside the sphere with radius $r$, and scaled by the dielectric constant:

$$\nabla\cdot \mathbf E=\frac{\rho}{\epsilon}$$.

It follows that the field will increase linearly with $r$ (because it will scale as $$\rm\frac{volume}{area}=\frac{\frac43 \pi r^3}{4\pi r^2}\propto r$$

Once you get to the edge of the sphere, the field will drop off in the usual $1/r^2$ manner.

This is a tricky thing to visualize with lines - it's a bit easier with colors:

[image]

(note - in this picture I assumed the dielectric constant of the sphere was 3; this suppresses the electric field inside compared to outside. Tip of the hat to Michael Seifert for pointing out that I had shown the case for $\epsilon_r=1$ without mentioning this explicitly).

Comment: Thanks, but colors don't do the trick. With colors one can't make out the direction of the field as with lines.

Comment: The field lines are purely radial from the center out. But since charge is distributed, field lines would have to "appear" at different distances - this is hard to do cleanly when the charge distribution is continuous (rather than discrete).

Comment: The electric field magnitude should be discontinuous at the surface of the sphere, as there is a bound surface charge there.

Comment: (For a dielectric medium, that is.  Your answer is correct for $\epsilon_r = 1$.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert that is an important point I completely omitted to mention - fixed now. Thank you!